# Hyphens and capitalization

Tags: capitalization

I am editing a document. The writer used the hyphenated form of "Company-Wide" in the article title. Note that the writer bot only hyphenated the word; the writer also capitalized "Wide." Is this correct?

Comment: Titles often init-cap individual words. Sometimes they do it to every word, sometimes they leave in minuscule small words like *a* and a few others.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Such questions are largely a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, organization, or publication, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Comment: [Title Case Converter](https://titlecaseconverter.com/) will let you choose different styles of title capitalization. There is no single style.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on the relevant style guide. This is the APA Style:

> Here are directions for implementing APA’s title case:
>
> 1. Capitalize the first word of the title/heading and of any subtitle/subheading;
> 2. Capitalize all “major” words (nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, and pronouns) in the title/heading, **including the second part of hyphenated major words (e.g., Self-Report not Self-report)**; and
> 3. Capitalize all words of four letters or more.

From: https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/03/title-case-and-sentence-case-capitalization-in-apa-style.html